# error during install of self-compiled linux kernel 3.2.69 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

i am getting problem in compile the **linux kernel 3.2.69** by using command,
**`make menuconfig`**  it is running successfully,
**`make`**  it is also running successfully

but when i use **`make install`** command it show this message

**sh /usr/src/linux-3.2.69/arch/x86/boot/install.sh 3.2.69 arch/x86/boot/bzImage System.map "/boot"**

it is any error..?
what should i do..?

Comment: I think you're missing the actual line containing the error. BTW: one reason to get an error on that line is that only the superuser (root) is allowed to write to the /boot directory.

Comment: already logged in as root..sometimes it shows some warning

Comment: thnx..any suggestion related to query..?

Comment: By now, I'm pretty sure you've not actually displayed the error here - the line you are printing is correct: all parameters are written as they should.

Comment: during **make** it shows many warnings. but there is no error..

Comment: Are your /boot/bzImage, /boot/System.map files updated?

Comment: No..should i download its tar.gz and update it..?

Comment: So, you posted a question about an error that is not in your post. It didn't update the files but there was no error? There's something weird going on here, and I'm sorry I cannot be of more help. This will be my last message.

Answer (score 0):

Try following these steps:

After `make`, run `make modules`, then `sudo make modules_install` and, finally, `sudo make install`. Superuser permissions are required in the last two steps, that's why You need to sudo them.

Finally run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda*` and `sudo update-grub` to be able to choose your compiled kernel from the grub menu. *Please check if /dev/sda is your target drive.*

This [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115620/configuring-compiling-and-installing-a-custom-linux-kernel) has good explanations about compiling and instaling a custom linux kernel.

Best regards.